# How do i retrieve the content data to blade from this json

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i'm encountered with an blade issue.

```
[{"banner_type":"2","content":"[\"e6aaaff3ae42af3af3a9cb6a45845da8f905c906Screenshotfrom2015-01-1917:17:31.png\",\"559a0e13473a22ac5bde041c5260257a12d1811eScreenshotfrom2015-01-2115:16:01.png\",\"559a0e13473a22ac5bde041c5260257a12d1811eScreenshotfrom2015-01-2208:49:53.png\",\"559a0e13473a22ac5bde041c5260257a12d1811eScreenshotfrom2015-01-2212:36:42.png\"]"}]
```

This is the json i'm getting from webservice, i need to get each image url and need to assign to a  tag . how could i achive it?

Comment: Within your controller decode the json, with `json_decode($data, true)` this will return an associative array of the data, then just pass this data to your view. And then loop through the content index as each of these are your images.

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach($json->content as $img)
    <img src="{{$img}}" alt="alt text">
@endforeach
```

From the information provided that is the most I can give you.

Comment: You forgot the braces. `{{ $img }}`

Answer (score 0):

For the given json, you can try something like this on your controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $json_string = '[{"banner_type":"2","content":"[\"e6aaaff3ae42af3af3a9cb6a45845da8f905c906Screenshotfrom2015-01-1917:17:31.png\",\"559a0e13473a22ac5bde041c5260257a12d1811eScreenshotfrom2015-01-2115:16:01.png\",\"559a0e13473a22ac5bde041c5260257a12d1811eScreenshotfrom2015-01-2208:49:53.png\",\"559a0e13473a22ac5bde041c5260257a12d1811eScreenshotfrom2015-01-2212:36:42.png\"]"}]';

    $json = json_decode($json_string, true);

    $images = json_decode($json[0]['content']);

    return view('index', compact('images'));
}
```

Then, on your blade view:

```
@foreach($images as $image)
    <img src="$image">
@endforeach
```